# Python Creating a dictionary of dictionaries structure, nested values are the same

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm attempting to build a data structure that can change in size and be posted to Firebase. The issue I am seeing is during the construction of the data structure. I have the following code written:

```
for i in range(len(results)):
designData = {"Design Flag" : results[i][5],
        "performance" : results[i][6]}
for j in range(len(objectiveNameArray)):
    objectives[objectiveNameArray[j]] = results[i][columnHeaders.index(objectiveNameArray[j])]
designData["objectives"] = copy.copy(objectives)
for k in range(len(variableNameArray)):
    variables[variableNameArray[k]] = results[i][columnHeaders.index(variableNameArray[k])]
designData["variables"] = copy.copy(variables)
for l in range(len(responseNameArray)):
    responses[responseNameArray[l]] = results[i][columnHeaders.index(responseNameArray[l])]
designData["responses"] = copy.copy(responses)
for m in range(len(constraintNameArray)):
    constraintViolated = False
    if constraintNameArray[m][1] == "More than":
        if results[i][columnHeaders.index(constraintNameArray[m][0])] > constraintNameArray[m][2]:
            constraintViolated = True
        else:
            constraintViolated = False
    elif constraintNameArray[m][1] == "Less than":
        if results[i][columnHeaders.index(constraintNameArray[m][0])] < constraintNameArray[m][2]:
            constraintViolated = True
        else:
            constraintViolated = False
    if constraintNameArray[m][0] in constraints:
        if constraints[constraintNameArray[m][0]]["violated"] == True:
            constraintViolated = True
    constraints[constraintNameArray[m][0]] = {"value" : results[i][columnHeaders.index(constraintNameArray[m][0])], "violated" : constraintViolated}
designData["constraints"] = copy.copy(constraints)
data[studyName][results[i][4]] = designData
```

When I include print(designData) inside of the for loop, I see that my results are changing as expected for each loop iteration.

However, if I include print(data) outside of the for loop, I get a data structure where the values added by the results array are all the same values for each iteration of the loop even though the key is different.

[Comparing print(data) and print(designData)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XAtis.png)

I apologize in advance if this isn't enough information this is my first post on Stack so please be patient with me.

Comment: I highly recommend posting your code snippet in the main body of the question if you want to get useful replies.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably because you put the variables like `objectives`, `variables`, `responses` directly to the `designData`. Try the following:

```
import copy

....
designData['objectives'] = copy.copy(objectives)
....
designData['variables'] = copy.copy(variables)
....
designData['responses'] = copy.copy(responses)
```

For similar questions, see [copy a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-to-clone-or-copy-a-list-in-python).